# Installation freezes while install Centos 7

Tags: centos, system-installation

I have an Nvidia GTX 960 and an Intel i7 CPU.  I am trying to install Centos 7 from an USB drive.  Originally I tried using a DVD but I kept getting an error about the linux kernel not being loaded.  Now I am getting this...

[image]

It just hangs here.

Comment: How long did you wait? I came across a situation, where Centos 7 setup paused for some time as well and I also though, it crashed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What method did you use to put the installation on the USB?  According to [centos wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey), you can't use unetbootin, but rather write the ISO directly to the USB(not the partition, but the device itself).

Comment: I was using unetbootin.  I am now writing the image with dd.  Hope that works.